# Periodic, linear increase in photon counts

Tags: experimental-physics, photons, particle-detectors

**Background:** In my experimental physics class I had to do an experiment like this [one](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205171) regarding the Bell-Inequality. 
For the data shown below the photons of blue laser diode in the state $|V\rangle$ are converted through Parametric Down Conversion into an product state $|H\rangle$ $\otimes$ $|H\rangle$. Photons are detected by two Avelanche Photo Diodes.

**Question:** I can see a linear increase in photon counts in both detectors that is also periodic. It is more prominent in detector 0 though. How can one explain this?

**Answered:** It was indeed an simple data processing error. As pointed out bei @probably_someone the data is exactly same what I should have noticed.

Every data point is the photon count over an acquisition time of 5 seconds. Therefore; time between data points is also 5 seconds.

[image: Photon counts in detector 0.]
[image: Photon counts in detector 1.]

Comment: Your link to the experiment links to your 1st graph instead. ... You have only shown 2 'periods' in each graph, but they do seem to be identical - which is highly suspicious, given the size of your error bars. Probably an artifact of how you have processed the data.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make sense that your data is _exactly_ the same from one period to the next.

Comment: The link to the experiment is now corrected. Unfortunately we don’t haven’t measured for longer time period, since we didn’t exspected what is shown above. I will check if something went wrong during data processing. Thanks